# Making an Android phone vibrate for 100ms C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've been trying out a few games on my phone in the last week, and saw that some used **vibration** as a "**feedback**" for the player when something happened, like:

- The player **crashed** into a wall;
- The player **did a perfect launch**;
- The player **received a big prize**...

*and so on*...

I really love how giving a little vibration or small shake to the phone, can basically tell the player that **something important** (for the game) **happened**, through an output that isn't only on the **screen** or comes from the **speaker**.

I'm developing my game with ***[Unity](https://unity.com)***.

In my game, I would make the phone vibrate **when the player crashes**, and when he **receives a big prize**, like I've seen other beautiful games doing.

> I've already tried using the default vibration: `Handheld.Vibrate()`, that worked, but it was lasting for **too much time** for my need and I wouldn't have been able to **change anything** in it.

I've read that, to do this, I would need to write a **separate plugin**, or use one that already exists. I have not found any working ones, and **have no idea how to write one**!

I would only need to call something like `vibrateFor(100)` where *100* are the *milliseconds*.

Some games, like "[Perfect Slices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perfect.slices)" seem to use this a lot.

So, **can anyone make such a plugin for me or point out an existing one for Android?**

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Edit**: Otherwise, could anyone explain to me in detail **how to use** [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/846461/how-to-control-vibration-duration-of-handheldvibra.html) **plugin** that seems to have worked for other people?

Unity version is ***2019.2.8f1***.

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/846461/how-to-control-vibration-duration-of-handheldvibra.html) help ?

Comment: @Youssef13 I had already seen that, but it is very unclear on where to write that code, and how to use it

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 **_2019.2.8f1_**

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis Do you know how to add permissions?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 no, I've never done that! I'm fairly new to unity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version **2018.3** Unity allows you to add **.java** files into your Unity Project and they are compiled when you build an Android player.

**1)** Copy the output **UnityAndroidVibrator.java** and **AndroidManifest.xml** files into the **Assets/Plugins/Android** directory in your Unity project.

**2)** Go to: **[File] > [build Settings] > [Player Settings] > [Player]** and copy package name.

**3)** In both classes find and replace **"uav.uav.uav"** package name with that you copied in step **2)**.

---

**UnityAndroidVibrator.cs** class:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class UnityAndroidVibrator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_EDITOR 
    private static AndroidJavaObject plugin = null;
    #endif


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () 
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR 
        plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("uav.uav.uav.UnityAndroidVibrator").CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
        #endif
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Vibrates For Given Amount Of Time.</para>
    /// <para>1 sec = 1000 Millseconds :)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DurationInMilliseconds">Duration in milliseconds.</param>
    public void VibrateForGivenDuration(int DurationInMilliseconds)
    {
        plugin.Call("VibrateForGivenDuration", DurationInMilliseconds);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stoping All Vibrate.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopVibrate()
    {
        plugin.Call("StopVibrate");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Customs Vibrate or Vibration with Pattern.</para>
    /// <para>Start without a delay</para>
    /// <para>Each element then alternates between vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep...</para>
    /// <para>long[] Pattern = {0, 100, 100, 300};</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Pattern">Pattern.</param>
    public void CustomVibrate(long[] Pattern)
    {
        plugin.Call("CustomVibrate", Pattern);
    }


}
```

**UnityAndroidVibrator.java** class:

```
package uav.uav.uav;

import android.os.Vibrator;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class UnityAndroidVibrator 
{
    private static UnityAndroidVibrator _instance;

    public UnityAndroidVibrator() {
    }

    public void VibrateForGivenDuration(int duration) {
        Vibrator vibs = (Vibrator)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService("vibrator");
        vibs.vibrate((long)duration);
    }

    public void StopVibrate() {
        Vibrator vibs = (Vibrator)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService("vibrator");
        vibs.cancel();
    }

    public void CustomVibrate(long[] Pattern) {
        Vibrator vibs = (Vibrator)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService("vibrator");
        vibs.vibrate(Pattern, -1);
    }

    public static UnityAndroidVibrator instance() 
    {
        if (_instance == null) 
        {
            _instance = new UnityAndroidVibrator();
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

---

**Note:** for example if your package name is "com.my.app" the resulting name would be:

*"UnityAndroidVibrator.cs" class:*

```
plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.my.app.UnityAndroidVibrator").CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
```

*"UnityAndroidVibrator.java" class:*

```
package com.my.app;

import android.os.Vibrator;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Xamarin developer not Unity but I believe that even outside of Xamarin projects you can reference the Xamarin.Essentials library - it's then as simple as calling

```
Xamarin.Essentials.Vibration.Vibrate(100);
```

When you want it to happen

On Android you have to add the vibration permission to the android manifest file. I'm not sure how to do this on unity but on xamarin you just add the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

to the manifest xml, it might be the same on Unity.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/vibrate?tabs=android