# Android Plugin in Unity - No returnvalue

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins

im trying to create an android plugin and import it in unity but i always get 0 as return value from the plugin method and i cant fix this issue.

Here is what i did:

AndroidStudio:
    -Created a new project 
    -Created a library module (package: com.e.timerlibrary)
    -Created Public Class "MyPlugin"
    -Build -> "Make Module 'timerlibrary'"
    -copied "classes.jar" file into "Assets/Plugins/Android" in Unity

MyPlugin only has one method:

```
 public int testmethode(){
        return 100;
    }
```

Unity:

```
    AndroidJavaObject JavaTimerClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.e.timerlibrary.MyPlugin");
    TextPlugin.text = JavaTimerClass.Call<int>("testmethode").ToString();
```

TextPlugin.text should display "100" but its always 0.
It seems like the name of the package cant be found

Hopefully someone can help me. Im new to unity&Androidstudio and followed many tutorials on youtube but i cant fix this issue.

Here is my full c# code. it's basically a timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float timeValue = 0;
    public float timeValuePause = 0;
    public float sliderValue;
    public Slider slider;
    public Text textTimer;
    public Text textTimerBtn;
    public Text TextPlugin;
    bool timerActive = false;
    bool backTimerActive = false;
    AndroidJavaObject JavaTimerClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.e.timerlibrary.MyPlugin");


    int testvar1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        textTimer.text = timeValue.ToString();
        //startService();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timerActive)
        {
            timeValue -= Time.deltaTime;
            textTimer.text = timeValue.ToString("f0");
            slider.value = timeValue;

            if (timeValue <= 0)
            {
                timerActive = false;
                textTimerBtn.text = "Start";
                timeValue = 0;
                slider.interactable = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTimerBtnClick()
    {
        textTimerBtn.text = timerActive ? "Start" : "Stop";
        timerActive = !timerActive;

        slider.interactable = false;

        if (timerActive==false)
        {
            timeValue = 0;
            textTimer.text = timeValue.ToString("f0");
            slider.interactable = true;
            slider.value = 0;
        }


    }

    public void GetValueOfSlider(float value)
    {
        if (timerActive == false)
        {
            textTimer.text = value.ToString("f0");
            timeValue = value;
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool pause) //Wird nur jeweils 1 mal ausgeführt!! 
    {
        if (pause)
        {
            //startService1();
            //TextPlugin.text = "pause";
            TextPlugin.text = JavaTimerClass.Call<int>("testmethode").ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //TextPlugin.text = "unpause";
            stopService1();
        }
    }


    void startService1()
    {
        /* if (!backTimerActive)
        {
          JavaTimerClass.Call("StartTimerService");
          backTimerActive = true;
        } */

        TextPlugin.text = JavaTimerClass.Call<int>("testmethode").ToString();

        //TextPlugin.text = JavaTimerClass.Call<int>("GetTime").ToString();
    }

    void stopService1()
    {
        //TextPlugin.text = JavaTimerClass.Call<int>("StopTimerService").ToString();
        backTimerActive = false;
    }

}
```

here is java code:

```
package com.e.timerlibrary;

public class MyPlugin {
    public int testmethode(){
        return 100;
    }
}
```

i know it looks pretty bad but im only trying to get the plugin to work

Comment: Please provide full java code part.

Comment: sorry. i edited with my full c# code. its just a timer and when the app is paused, the plugin should send the int value of 100 to the c# script

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: current version is 2019.3.13f1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an Android phone vibrate for 100ms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123343/making-an-android-phone-vibrate-for-100ms-c-sharp)

Comment: i changed my java package name to my unity package name, changed package name in AndroidManifest.xml too and copied "AndroidManifest.xml" and "MyPlugin.java" into Assets/plugins/android but that doesn't seem to work